# correlated equilibrium,Nash equilibrium, equivalent definition, unclear comment in the Tirole's Fudenberg's book

Tags: game-theory, correlation, nash-equilibrium

[Here](http://econ.ucsb.edu/~garratt/210B/Correlatedequilibriumfudenbergandtirole.pdf) on page 58, there is a sentence in the first paragraph which is completely unclear to me:
    "(The only reason this isn't completely obvious is that there may be several information sets $h_i$ where player $i$ played $s_i$, in which case   his information set has been reduced to $s_i$ alone.)"

First, "reduced" mean loosing information or on the other hand specifying more precisely to $s_i$?

***What is the precise meaning of the sentence quoted?*** I.e. why different
information sets $h_i$ where $i$ played $s_i$ lead to ""new?""
information set $s_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous sentence reads

> Given $\mathfrak s=(\mathfrak s_1,\dots, \mathfrak s_n)$, equilibrium with respect to $(Ω,\{H_i\},\tilde p)$, set $p(s)=\sum\tilde p(ω)$ where the sum runs over all $ω\in Ω$ such that $$\mathfrak  s_i(ω)=s_i $$ for every $i\in I$.

So, all states of the world $ω\in Ω$ where $\mathfrak s$ was recommended are now identified as one state. E.g. assume $n=2$ players and two states $ω_1$ and $ω_2$, where the players are recommended under $\mathfrak s$ to play $s_1(ω_1)=s_1(ω_2)=s_1$ and $s_2(ω_1)=s_2(ω_2)=s_2$. So, the players know in which state they are and then "hear" their recommendation.

Now, under the transformation, you identify these two states as one, called $(s_1,s_2)$. This occurs with probability $\tilde p(ω_1)+\tilde p(ω_2)$ and the players do not get informed about the exact $ω$ that has occured (so they lose information) but only about the recommendation.

Comment: Line "to play $s_1(ω_1)=s_1(ω_1)=s_1$" should read "to play $s_1(ω_1)=s_1(ω_2)=s_1$"? And in $p(ω_1)+p(ω_2)$, $p$ is not defined on $ω_1,ω_2$.

Comment: @user122424 Two typos in 4 lines... Thank you for the correction.

Comment: "as one, called $(s_1,s_2)$" should read "as one, called $(ω_1,ω_2)$"? if not, why?

Comment: Read the definition of the set $J(s_i)$ and the paragraph below at the point: "....when this finer information... recommended strategy". I think this will clarify to you what happens. No, if I call this state $(s_1,s_2)$ instead of something else, that you can change. But avoid $ω$ here, since you will get confused.

Comment: I reread the second displayed formula (the big Sum) on page 58, but I'm still unsure about what it intends to say. Can you please help?

Comment: Moreover I do not understand why $i$ in $$\mathfrak  s_i(ω)=s_i $$ is your first paragraph is the same on both sides? Is $s_i$ just a general element in $S_i$?

Comment: Did you read the sentence "....when this finer information... recommended strategy"? This is the best explanation I think. An ad-hoc example: Say at the states of the world "$ω_1=$rain" and "$ω_2=$snow" you are told to hold and umbrella (in equilibrium). And there are no other states where you are told to hold an umbrella. Now, identify these two states as one, summing up their probabilities and ignore the actual state. The only information you get is to hold an umbrella.

Comment: Yes, this is the same, but equality holds for all $i \in I$.

Comment: OK but $i$th player may use his $j$th strategy, right?

Comment: Yes, $s_i$ is just any strategy of player $i$, (here the one used under equilibrium).

Comment: I've found out what in fact was unclear to me: it is the point that $\Omega=S$ whence states of the world and all pure strategies are mixed up...It is this and that the player $1$ is told besides $s_1$ also $s_2$ in $(s_1,s_2)$ while he has nothing to do with $s_2$...

Comment: Yes, the first part, that Ω=S, was clear to me. But you are right about the second, player i is told also s_j and I did not stress that part, I got confused as well with this last one

Comment: As you proved very good in explaining the probabilities in the FT book you could perhaps give me also a hint on something similar? [Here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/Minded%20Driver.pdf) on page 115, how was computed the first displayed fraction with halves following $h(p,q)$? The term in front of "[" is most wanted. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user122424 Actually, the moderators here do not like it when people ask questions in the comments and more or less I agree. Feel free to post it as a separate question and just let me know, so that I can consider it later today!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019833/game-absent-minded-driver-unclear-probability-coefficient

Comment: A new question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286392/fudenberg-tirole-book-rationalizability-and-iterated-strict-dominance-coincide)